# libGDX - Invert x-axis

Tags: libgdx

is it possible to invert the x-axis (or in other words to change it's direction) of the coordinate system in libGDX? Here is a sketch:

[image]

Best regards!

Comment: Not in general, but there are many places where you can change it. In which context do you want to change it?

Comment: The general answer would be to multiply the x coordinate by -1. That will invert the axis. But it depends on the context of where do you want to change this?

Comment: I want to get the origin (0,0) from bottom left to bottom right. Because there is a method to change the direction of the y-axis, I thought maybe there is a method for the x-axis, too.
But okay, to achieve this I must compute x' = width-x (instead of multiply -1).

Comment: Thats still multiplying by -1 and adding width. Also why do you need this in the first place?

Comment: "Thats still multiplying by -1 and adding width." - Yeah, that's what I wrote ;-)
In my program I have to draw boxes. Sometimes from left to right and sometimes from right to left (and the quantity is changing). It would be more easier if I just can change the origin from left to right. But if there is no such method, I do it at the usually way.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the camera position. In this case rotate the camera 180 degrees around the x-axis and y-axis also (flipping positive for both).

```
cam.rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), 180f); //x rotation 
cam.rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 180f); //y rotation    
cam.update();
```

You only have to do this once.